# Dropdown menu with user input text field and multiple selections

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to do a dropdown menu with user input, but I want the user to be able to add multiple options.

I was trying to do a datalist with this, but when it came time for multiple inputs then I read that datalist can only do that with email and files.

Here's an example of my current code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="users" id="users" list="allowedUsers">
<datalist id="editUsers">
    <option value="bob"></option>
</datalist>
```

JS:

```
$('#users').keypress(function(event){
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which)
    if(keyCode == '13') {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        $(#editUsers).append('<option value="'+inputVal+'">'+inputVal+'</option>')
    }
});
```

The user can then click on a value and if they click on another either add that one in or when they do a comma then they can click to add.  Not sure what would be easiest.

Thanks!

Comment: You want add option to the dropdown when user types in input on a keypress ? for example if i type `a` - you want `a` as an option in the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Chek this: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

And in mid time maybe you could get away with something like this:

**1 example:**

It works by clicking the items, input is readonly...

```js
$('#users').focus(function(){
$('#editUsers').show();
});

$('#editUsers').change(function() {
    var val = $("#editUsers option:selected").text();
    var inpoutVal = $('#users').val();
    if (inpoutVal!=="")   {
 $('#users').val(inpoutVal+","+val)
  }else{
   $('#users').val(val)
  }    
});
```

```css
#editUsers {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="users" id="users" readonly>
  <select id="editUsers" multiple>
    <option>Bob</option>
    <option>Jhon</option>
    <option>Yoda</option>
  </select>
```

**2nd example:**
this is just something i trued to cook up, but it got out of hand, anyway try to pres some starting letter like B, or Y, then add cooma `,` . Anyway it does not definlty work as it should but maybe will someone get inspired by this failed attempt. ;)

Its late here cant work on it anymore...

```js
$('#users').focus(function() {
  $('#editUsers').show();
});

$("#users").bind('input', function() {
  console.clear();
  var inputVal = $("#users").val();
  var inputVal2 = inputVal.split(",");
  var last = inputVal2[inputVal2.length - 1];
  $('#editUsers option').each(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if (selVal.indexOf(last) > -1 && inputVal.indexOf(",") <= 0) {
      $("#users").val(selVal + ",")
    } else if (selVal.indexOf(last) > -1 && inputVal.indexOf(",") > -1) {
      var newval = $("#users").val();
      var newval2 = newval.split(",");
      newval2.pop()
      newval2
      $("#users").val(newval2 + "," + selVal)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#editUsers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="users" id="users">
<select id="editUsers" multiple>
  <option>Bob</option>
  <option>Jhon</option>
  <option>Yoda</option>
</select>
```